# Go send and receive with buffered channel

Tags: go

i'm trying to implement a pipeline using buffered channel with size one, it will accept incoming message, print it out and wait some time then pass it forward. The main problem is that reading gobyexample tutorial I decided to implement it using select statement, but I cannot figure out how to make channel block until it will pass the message forward.

```golang
func runVertex(vertex Vertex) {

    newVertex := findVertex(vertex)

    var packet handledPacket

    for {
        select {
        case packet.packet = <-someChannel:
            fmt.Println("msg received")
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        case someOtherChannel <- packet.packet:
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        default:
            time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want to receive the message from someChannel, then subsequently send the same message to someOtherChannel, and repeat?

Comment: `I cannot figure out how to make channel block until it will pass the message forward`.  The default behavior of sending on a channel is blocking until ready.  You've overridden this by putting it inside a `select` statement with a `default` case.  There doesn't seem to be any legitimate reason why you've used `select` here as every step of your problem concerns only one channel, and you don't want `default` behavior.

Comment: You might find the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/) more helpful and authoritative than Go by Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `select` to do the thing you described:

```
for {
  packet.packet =<- someChannel:
  fmt.Println("msg received");
  time.Sleep(time.Second);
  someOtherChannel<-packet.packet:
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The operation of receiving something from a channel is blocking, you don't need to do something special. And `select`s are intended to let you either handle multiple channels or somehow react if there is nothing new in the channel(s) you are watching. Here is an example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func messagesPrinter(channel1 chan string, channel2 chan string) {
    var message string

    for {
        select {
        case message = <-channel1:
            fmt.Println("A message from channel 1:", message)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        case message = <-channel2:
            fmt.Println("A message from channel 2:", message)
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
        default: // Optional part
            fmt.Println("Now message yet...")
            time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c1 := make(chan string)
    c2 := make(chan string)
    go messagesPrinter(c1, c2)
    c1 <- "Hello"
    c1 <- "How are you?"
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    c2 <- "I'm fine!"
}
```